# Allocating array after accepting size from user

Tags: arrays, c, indexing, declaration

I was writing *something like* this in C.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x;
    printf("enter no of elements/n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    int arr[x];

    return 0;
}
```

This works fine, but many said it's not a good practice or it is illegal? Can anybody give reasons for it?

Update: anything wrong other than
portability, or undefined size?

Comment: What happens if the user enters `-3`? What happens if the user enters `0`? What happens if the user enters `"foobar"`? **Always** validate incoming data! Always... (PS: the capitalised letters and the mystery of the datatype of `Arr[ ]` suggest you should edit/correct this question before the DV's accumulate...)

Comment: As hinted by the previous comment, the line `Arr[x];` is not valid, as you are not declaring a data type. I suggest that you [edit] the question to fix it.

Comment: You may want to read about [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). The most important thing to note is that they are not supported by all compilers, because they are an optional feature.

Comment: You cannot do this without the size: how do you allocate memory for an input of undetermined size? Some other strategies: have a fixed maximum size; read up to the limit and then expand the buffer. Impossible to tell which one would well with only this problem statement.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your actual code looks something like the following, it will compile.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n;
    printf("Enter number of elements:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int arr[n];

    // Other stuff...
}
```

However, there are a few issues.

- Variable length arrays (or VLAs) are not supported by all compilers. Notably MSVC. Relying on them will impact the portability of your code.
- You never validate the input. `scanf` may not have read a valid number, and even if it did, `0` or a negative number are going to lead to undefined behavior.

What can you do about these?

- You can dynamically allocate memory for your array rather than using a VLA.
- You can write a function which checks the input from the user and validates that it's a positive integer. It might prompt for repeat input or return a value that `main` can check and then gracefully exit the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINE_LENGTH 1024

int get_positive_int(void);

int main(void) {
    int n = get_positive_int();
    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

    if (arr == NULL) {
        printf("Array allocation failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Other stuff...
}

int get_positive_int(void) {
    char line[LINE_LENGTH] = "";

    while (1) {
        printf("Enter number of elements:\n");

        int input = -1;

        fgets(line, LINE_LENGTH, stdin);
        if (sscanf(line, "%d", &input) == 1 && input > 0)
            return input;
    }
}
```

Comment: "You never validate the input." --> Yes it is good to get the return value of `scanf()`.  You may want to apply that good advice to `fgets(line, LINE_LENGTH, stdin);` too.  Initializing `line[]` is not sufficient when `fgets()` experiences an input failure.

Answer (score 3):

> but many said it's not a good practice or it is illegal?

**Legal?**

Yes, yet depends on the compiler version and optional support.

[Variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (VLA) like `int Arr[x];` are supported starting in C99 and optionally in C11 and later (research `__STDC_NO_VLA__`).

This impacts portability.

**Good practice?**

- Not checking the return value of `scanf("%d",&x);` is weak.
- With `int Arr[x];`, if `x <= 0`, we have *undefined behavior* (UB).
- If `x` is large, we risk memory exhaustion like stack overflow or other UB.

VLAs are OK when:

- The size is positive and not too large
- Portability is not a large concern.

Use the right tool for the job.
VLAs have limited cases when they are the best solution.

**Better example usage**

```
  #define VLA_LIMIT 42

  printf("enter no of elements ");
  int x;
  if (scanf("%d",&x) != 1) {
    Handle_Input_Error();  // TBD code
  } 
  if (x <= 0 || x > VLA_LIMIT) {
    Handle_Range_Error();  // TBD code
  } 
  int Arr[x];
  ...
```

Comment: Arguably, if the limit is 42, you could just do `int Arr[42]:` and increase portability.

Comment: @BoP True, yet depends on coding goals.  Consider a parser function that may re-enter and so conserving stack space per call is useful.